# Angular: how to keep resetting $timeout on scroll events, and let $timeout finish otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm working on a little controller that watches for a scroll event and applies a CSS class, and applies a different CSS class. Long story short I'm trying to have the scrollbar thumb disappear when you're not scrolling, and appear when you ARE scrolling (like the scrollbar thumb on an iPhone).

I'm having trouble implementing it. My thought process doing this is:

```
1) On page load, set a $scope variable to false. 
2) Watch for a scroll event on the div I want.
3) Once the scroll event starts, set the $scope variable to true. 
4) Keep on resetting the $timeout whenever a scroll event fires.
5) In the timeout function, set the $scope variable back to false if the $timeout finishes.
6) In the HTML, set an ng-class to watch for this $scope variable.
```

I thought that sounded pretty simple, but I'm having a lot of trouble implementing it and I'm not sure if it's just something about $timeout that I'm missing, or if I'm just thinking in circles and don't realize it yet.

This is the controller I have set up for it (An actual working JSFiddle is linked beneath this wall of code):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('scrollingApp')
        .controller('scrollbarController', scrollbarController);

    function scrollbarController($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.actuallyScrolling = false;

        $scope.scrolling = function() {
            $('.container').on('scroll', function(event) {
                $scope.actuallyScrolling = true;
                console.log('before checkScroll ', $scope.actuallyScrolling);
                checkScroll();
            });
        };

        var checkScroll = function() {
            var timeoutEnded = false;
            $timeout(function() {
                if($scope.actuallyScrolling) {
                    $scope.actuallyScrolling = false;
                    console.log('inside $timeout if statement', $scope.actuallyScrolling);
                }
            }, 1000);
            console.log($scope.actuallyScrolling);
        };
        $scope.scrolling();
    }
})();
```

I set up a JSFiddle here (https://jsfiddle.net/hurgledurf/k5naeora/) with the code I have so far (hopefully it's self-explanatory), and would appreciate any help/insight anyone might have. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular of not... To "reset" a timeout on scroll should be done this way:

```
var timer;
$('.container').on('scroll', function(event) {
  console.log('User is actually scrolling...');

  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('User finished scrolling.');
  },500);

});
```

It replace this chunk of your code:

```
$('.container').on('scroll', function(event) {
  $scope.actuallyScrolling = true;
  console.log('before checkScroll ', $scope.actuallyScrolling);
  checkScroll();
});
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I'm curious though, how come all I have to do is declare a variable named timer and then run clearTimeout on it? How come I don't need to make timer a setTimeout function before running clearTimeout?

Comment: When `clearTimeout()` is called... **If** the argument passed is a `setTimeout()`, it gets cleared. **if not**, like on the very first occurance, nothing happens anyway. It doesn't throw an error. Then the variable is defined as a `setTimeout` to count down 500 milliseconds... But before it can execute its callback, another scroll event occurs and the timers gets cleared. A new 500 ms countdown starts... And so on.. Until there is no scroll event occuring for at least 500 ms... That is when the callback function is finally executed.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: the principal is good... but "angular or not" not a good thing to say when you are using angular, as you are using jquery, and alot of newbies will put jquery into their angular code - Also the base code is crap (had jquery in it ffs) .. so i understand why you u said it fair enough